# class private variable corruption

Tags: c++, c, memory, gcc, memory-corruption

I have a std::vector of some class of the form

```
class A{
 public:
 A():i(someNumber){}
 void useI() const{
   //do something with i
 }
 // No destructor defined
 private:
  int i;
};
```

My code is looping through each data point and call `useI()` on each element in the array. After few hundred iterations, the variable `i` got corrupted and I have no idea why. The situation can be replicated. I know there is not too much details here but any suggestion on what to check is deeply appreciated.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a declaration for `someNumber`.

Comment: How are you iterating over the vector ??

Comment: This is really not enough detail to give an answer. Strip down the calling code to a short working example and post it here. If you're lucky you'll find the bug yourself while doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely to cause such a thing is overindexing an array access to a pointer that does not point to the correct place.  Now, finding where this happens is not trivial, but tools, like valgrind can help.

Working with C-style strings can also easily end up overindexing the string if not properly terminated or the holding buffer's size is applied incorrectly

Another cause could be double-delete/free of a pointer that also corrupts memory